# Object of class Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\... could not be converted to int

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class Proxies_*CG*_\App\Entity\Professional could not be converted to int").

I am developing in Symfony 4. This is my first time when I work with 2 entities linked together.

My twig template:

```
        {% for contact in contacts %}
        {% if contact.professional == professional.id %}
        <tr>
        <th>{{ contact.giftCheck }}</th>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

My Entities: Professional(what is related to contact)

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PlaceComment::class, mappedBy="professional", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $placeComments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //some more collections ...
        $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Contact[]
     */
    public function getContacts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->contacts;
    }

    public function addContact(Contact $contact): self
    {
        if (!$this->contacts->contains($contact)) {
            $this->contacts[] = $contact;
            $contact->setProfessional($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeContact(Contact $contact): self
    {
        if ($this->contacts->removeElement($contact)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($contact->getProfessional() === $this) {
                $contact->setProfessional(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

My Entities: Contact

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ContactRepository::class)
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $confirmed;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $completed;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=GiftCheck::class, inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $giftCheck;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Professional::class, inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $professional;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $confirmationDate;

    function __construct($giftCheck, $professional)
    {
        $this->giftCheck = $giftCheck;
        $this->professional = $professional;
        $this->date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
//a bunch of setters and getters
```

Comment: `if contact.professional.id == professional.id`, I presume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the contact.professional.id to be equal to the professional.id, that all:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
  {% if contact.professional.id == professional.id %}
    <tr>
     <th>{{ contact.giftCheck }}</th>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```